# azure cli command to enable system assigned managed identity when creating event subscription for event grid system topic

Tags: azure-devops, azure-eventgrid

When creating event subscription for event grid system topic, we have an option to enable managed identity to system assigned .Please give the azure cli command to enable this managed identity when creating event subscription for event grid system topic.

I am unable to find a parameter which is used to enable managed identity using azure cli. Please give the azure cli command to enable this managed identity when creating event subscription for event grid system topic.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/cli/azure/eventgrid/system-topic/event-subscription?view=azure-cli-latest) this is not possible for system topics to use managed identity via azure CLI. You need to use the Portal for this purpose.

It is only possible for [custom topics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/eventgrid/event-subscription?view=azure-cli-latest). More details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/managed-service-identity#create-an-event-subscription-by-using-a-managed-identity-for-delivery) for custom topics.

I created an issue on [the github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/26910) for t.his